# OpenUrl command in Alexa simulator

Tags: alexa-presentation-language

I am trying to test OpenURL command like below , but no page is opened in Alexa simulator.Any clue on this issue please ?.

```
{
  "type": "OpenURL",
  "source": "https://www.amazon.com/",
  "onFail": {
    "type": "SetValue",
    "componentId": "errorText",
    "property": "text",
    "value": "Unable to open Amazon.com (${event.source.value})"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
The browser was blocking the Url.